# Windows 7 'Choose Default Program' for Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7

I've installed Python3.8 64bit into C:/Python38 on a Win7 machine (I know, but let's assume I can't upgrade to Win10 !). I've googled and tried everything but I can't set C:/Python38/python.exe to be the default program to run .py files when I double click on them.

If I do the usual 'Open With->Choose Default Program' and browse to C:/Python38/python.exe it will not assign it.

Sounds like a FAQ, but I can't find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had `Python2.7` installed
when I installed `3.8` (including the Python Launcher) the Registry key  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command` was not updated.

I set it manually to `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`

Now the launcher points to 3.8